# Bigquery.jobs().query returns epoch time 1.295353708E9 for timestamp column

Tags: java, google-bigquery

`Bigquery.jobs().query().execute` returns epoch time for timestamp and that epoch time includes dot with trailing alphanumeric value(`1.295353708E9`) thus converting that value to a Java timestamp fails;

```
Object v = checkNullAndGetColumnValue(columnIndex);
long epoch = Long.parseLong(v.toString());
String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (epoch*1000));
```

the returned value `1.295353708E9` is the same as `1295353708` however not sure what the best way to handle that as bq web UI renders it.

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: It is worth noting that BigQuery uses seconds _specifies the number of seconds_ [1] (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery#datatypes) whereas Java uses **mili**seconds. That is why `* 1000` is needed.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
 long epoch = Double.valueOf("1.295353708E9").longValue();
 String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
         .format(new Date (epoch*1000));
```

With the given example value, the `date` string resolves to `01/18/2011 21:28:28`.

Answer (score 3):

I do this way

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    double d = Double.parseDouble("1.295353708E9");
    long l = (long) d * 1000;
    cal.setTimeInMillis(l);

    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(cal
            .getTime());
```

Anyway, i think bigquery timestamp format is "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"